# Eclipse Android New Activity Pending Changes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, tfs

I want to create a new Activity in my Android program but got stuck at the final step after naming the Activity. Refer to screenshot. Nothing happens even I click finish and I am not able to update the lists of files pending above.

Could it due to the Team Foundation Server that I connects on? But previously I do not face this problem. Now I am stuck with no solution, hope someone is able to enlighten me.

Thank you.

Screenshot: http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h306/teapeng/Untitled_zps7aa2bfba.jpg

Comment: what is it saying when you click on Finish?

Comment: It says "Preview - Optionally review pending changes". Click on the image link for further details.

Comment: did you solved your problem? If so then please give the solution please.

Comment: @Programmer, are you facing the issue right now? My problem is solved, I guess the latest Eclipse no longer has this issue.

Comment: Yes I am facing this issue right now! I am using Eclipse Version 23.0.2.1259578. It is IDE for android development, downloaded from android developer's site. Actually I am able to create an empty activity but cant create activity with an action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Create Empty Activity" instead of "Create Blank Activity" ,That worked for me for the while.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have encountered the same problem and this is what I did. I worked for me.

checkout the items

```
AndroidManifest.xml
res/values/strings.xml
```

delete

```
gen/com.projectname/R.java
```

(it should be able to recreate itself)

Hope this helps.